# How to insert HTML elements in a div element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

How to produce all this code into a div element using JavaScript.

```
<div id=parentDiv>
    <div id="question1"> 
        QuestionNo 1
        <button onclick="setOption(1,1)">A</button>
        <button onclick="setOption(1,2)">B</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to insert the div **question1 'n'** number of times with ids as **question2**, **question3** also the the parameters for calling the function **setOption** should be like **setOption(i,1), setOption(i,2)** for every **questioni**.

I have tried using this.

```
var paper = document.getElementById("paper");
for (i = 1; i <= NOQ; i++) {
    paper.innerHTML += '<div id="question' + i + '">'           

    var element = document.getElementById("question" + i);

    element.innerHTML += 'QuestionNo ' + i + ' :';
    element.innerHTML += '<button onclick="setOption(' + i + ',1)">A</button>';
    element.innerHTML += '<button onclick="setOption(' + i + ',2)">B</button>';
}
```

However, this method takes a lot of time when value of **n** goes more than 200 or so, which makes me think of a loading screen. But the problem is all the n element are banged on the screen at once and not one by one, and same happens with my loading screen. The loading screen is also banged with the other elements at the end of the process.

My questions are, Is this method legal at all? Why is this taking so much amount of time? Is the appendchild method better than this (if yes can someone help me how to insert all this using append child method)? How can i show a loading screen showing progress as each element loads?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed a few errors but you get general idea.

```
 var paper = document.getElementById("paper");
    for(i=1; i<=NOQ; i++){
        paper.innerHTML+='<div id="question'+i+'"></div>'             

        var element = document.getElementById("question" + i);

        element.innerHTML='QuestionNo '+i+' :<button onclick="setOption('+i+',1)">A</button><button onclick="setOption('+i+',2)">B</button>';
}
```

This shouldn't take long to load.
If you are getting long load times, consider pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

### HTML

```
<div id=parentDiv>
    <div id="question1"> 
        <script>
            fn_generate(10);//give any no. in place of 10 i.e. the no of qstns you want.
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
fn_generate=function(n)
{
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        document.write("QuestionNo " + i);
        for(j=1; j<=2; j++)
            document.write("<button onclick='setOption("+i+","+j+")'>Ans" + j + "</button>");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
```